# jQuery fadein fadeout Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Can anyone help me to implement the following jQuery looped auto slideshow. The steps are as follows: 1.First fadeIn the slideshow image and after that fadein the caption background and lastly fadeIn the caption text.Here the Attached files are the visual example.

`http://www.markupxpert.com/slideshow/step1.jpg`

`http://www.markupxpert.com/slideshow/step2.jpg`

`http://www.markupxpert.com/slideshow/step3.jpg`

Thanks, Paul

Comment: ...and what're you having a problem with? What've you tried, and what went wrong?

Comment: Hello..David and EviIP,I am just googling it but could not find any jQuery plugin like that.Do you have any referrence site like that?

Comment: any jQuery like that ? You mean a plugin or ? Have you ever coded something in jQuery  ?

Comment: yes plugin..that was typing mistake..sorry for that..Thanks EviIP

Comment: I made an answer with the plugin you are searching for !

Answer (score 2):

**[About jQuery `fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)**

`fadeIn` has a callback function which is called when the animation is complete. You can use it to start your second animation as belows:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {

   // 1st anim starts here
   $('#slideshowImage').fadeIn('slow', function() {

       // 1st anim ended, 2nd starts here     
       $('#captionBackground').fadeIn('slow', function() {

         // 2nd anim ended, 3rd stars here
          $('#captionText').fadeIn('slow');        

       });        
   });
});
```

The animation part starts within the click event's callback function as I commented it out. Of course you probably don't want to start the animation by clicking on a button but rather than in a loop. In this case you only need the middle part.

Also, you need to modify the jQuery selectors in order to `fadeIn` the proper elements. *(Probably they're not called `#slideshowImage` or so...)*

Comment: Hello papaiatis thank for code,can you help me to make it carousel( steps are fadein and fadeout after certain time).Its not on the click event.It will load by the time of page loading.Thanks

Comment: Can you accept my answer first? Then you can create another question and we will be happy to help you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you not to implement that behaviour. There are dozens of jQuery slideshows out there you can use or modify as  you want.

Google for `jQuery slideshow` and find the one that best suits your needs.

Some examples:

[25 jQuery Image Gallery/Slider Tutorials and Plugins](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/)

[33 Powerful jQuery Slideshow (Sliders) Plugins and Tutorials](http://www.themeflash.com/30-powerful-jquery-slideshow-sliders-plugins-and-tutorials/)

[23 Best jQuery Slideshow (Gallery) Plugins](http://slodive.com/freebies/best-jquery-slideshow-gallery-plugins/)

[21 Brilliant jQuery Image Gallery/Slideshow Plugins](http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/21-brilliant-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins/)

[20 Best jQuery Slideshow / Photo Gallery Plugins](http://graphicalerts.com/20-best-jquery-slideshow-image-photo-gallery-plugins/)

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

This is the plugin you are searching for: http://fancybox.net/
Most of the galleries are done with that. Check out the documentation and if there are some things you don't understand feel free to post a question about it :)
cheers

Comment: Sorry EvilP, The slideshow what i want to implement is really full customized,Could not find any  like this by googling.